# How to get around iOS iap promo codes being "valid only in the United States"

Tags: ios

I'm trying out the new IAP promo codes, but I'm getting a "This code is only valid on the United State store". When I generated it, there was no option to select a specific country, nor is my developer account based in the United States.

How to get around that country requirement?!?